# Binding 2 tables into 1 datagrid with outer join?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have table customer and table contract with one-many relationship (1 customer has many contracts)
I want to bind them into 1 datagrid that will list all of my customers and all contracts related to specific customer.

The SQL query is :

```
select * from vbdadvertisement.customer cus left join vbdadvertisement.contract con
on cus.id = con.Customer_id
```

I tried to create a datagrid bound into customer table then use  :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ContractNo" Binding="{Binding Path=contracts/ContractNo}" />
```

But this method will list only the first contract of customer instead of all of the contracts.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the [RowDetails](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx#rowdetails) property of the datagrid. you can then simply bind your "many" relationship to the details.